# An equivalent definition for shamir secret sharing polynomial scheme?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, polynomials

Taking into account [this paper](https://downloads.hindawi.com/journals/scn/2019/5134534.pdf) I will write here a definition that the authors provide.

$\textbf{Definition:}$ (linear secret sharing scheme). A $(t,n)$ secret sharing scheme is a linear secret sharing scheme when the $n$ shares, $v_1,v_2,...,v_n$ can be presented as in Equation $(5)$

$$(v_1,v_2,...,v_n)=(k_1,k_2,...,k_t)H,\quad (5)$$

where $H$ is a public $t × n$ matrix whose any $t × t$ submatrix is not singular. The vector $(k_1,k_2,...,k_n)$ is randomly chosen by the dealer.

According to Defnition, we can see that Shamir’s $(t, n)$ secret sharing scheme is a linear scheme. Let

$$f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_{t-1}x^{t-1},\quad (6)$$

Te shares $v_i = f(i)$, $i = 1, 2, ..., n$ can be presented as in Equation $(7)$

$$(v_1,v_2,...,v_n)=(a_0,a_1,...,a_{t-1})H,\quad (7)$$

How is $(7)$ equivalent to $(6)$? in some definitions it quotes $y_i= f(x_i)$ or $y_i= f(x_i)mod{p}$ how do they differ with $(7)$?

Does the above definition means that we can have another representation for polynomials based in $(7)$?